# Multiple Hibernate event listeners registered in resources.groovy

Tags: hibernate, grails

In our application we are having two hibernate event listeners.One for audit logging and another for indexing in the Solr server.

But the issue which we are facing is only one gets called as of now.
Please find below the configuration details :

---

Code snippet

```
A] Inside  AuditLoggingProjPlugin.groovy:
def loadAfter = ['core','hibernate']

        def doWithSpring = {
          if (manager?.hasGrailsPlugin("hibernate")) {
            auditLogListener(AuditLogListener) {
                grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
                sessionFactory   = sessionFactory
                verbose          = application.config?.auditLog?.verbose?:false
                transactional    = application.config?.auditLog?.transactional?:false
                sessionAttribute = application.config?.auditLog?.sessionAttribute?:""
                actorKey         = application.config?.auditLog?.actorKey?:""
                logIds           = application.config?.auditLog?.logIds?:false
                replacementPatterns = application.config?.auditLog?.replacementPatterns?:null
                propertyMask        = application.config?.auditLog?.propertyMask?:""
            }
          }
        }

        def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->
          // pulls in the bean to inject and init
          AuditLogListener listener = applicationContext.getBean("auditLogListener")
          // allows to configure the Actor name Closure in the config
          listener.setActorClosure(application.config?.auditLog?.actorClosure?:AuditLogListenerUtil.actorDefaultGetter )
          listener.init()
                // allows user to over-ride the maximum length the value stored by the audit logger.
          if(application.config?.auditLog?.TRUNCATE_LENGTH) {
            listener.truncateLength = new Long(application.config?.auditLog?.TRUNCATE_LENGTH)
          }
        }
B] Inside  SolrIndexProjPlugin.groovy:
def doWithSpring = {
        // TODO Implement runtime spring config (optional)
        if (manager?.hasGrailsPlugin("hibernate")) {
            searchPersistenceListener(SearchPersistenceListener) {
                solrIndexService =  ref("solrIndexService")
            }
          }
        //start of search indexing listener
        //this might need to be commented out if other plugins are not up to date
       /* searchPersistenceListener(com.xms.core.search.SearchPersistenceListener){
            solrIndexService =  ref("solrIndexService")
        }

        hibernateEventListeners(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateEventListeners) {
          listenerMap = ['post-commit-insert': searchPersistenceListener,
                         'post-commit-update': searchPersistenceListener,
                         'post-commit-delete': searchPersistenceListener]
        }*/
        //end of search indexing listener
    }

    def doWithDynamicMethods = { ctx ->
        // TODO Implement registering dynamic methods to classes (optional)
    }

    def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->
        // TODO Implement post initialization spring config (optional)

        def listeners = applicationContext.sessionFactory.eventListeners
        SearchPersistenceListener listener = applicationContext.getBean("searchPersistenceListener") 
        ['postCommitInsert', 'postCommitUpdate', 'postCommitDelete'].each({
           addEventTypeListener(listeners, listener, it)
        })
    }

    def addEventTypeListener(listeners, listener, type) {
        def typeProperty = "${type}EventListeners"
        def typeListeners = listeners."${typeProperty}"

        def expandedTypeListeners = new Object[typeListeners.length + 1]
        System.arraycopy(typeListeners, 0, expandedTypeListeners, 0, typeListeners.length)
        expandedTypeListeners[-1] = listener

        listeners."${typeProperty}" = expandedTypeListeners
    }
```

I strongly think I am missing out something in the configuration in the project plugin and thing is am completely lost.

Strongly require help.

Regards,MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I was not registering the listener properly:
Added below code snippet:

```
['postCommitInsert','postCommitUpdate', 'postCommitDelete'].each({
       addEventTypeListener(listeners, listener, it)
    })
}

def addEventTypeListener(listeners, listener, type) {
    def typeProperty = "${type}EventListeners"
    def typeListeners = listeners."${typeProperty}"

    def expandedTypeListeners = new Object[typeListeners.length + 1]
    System.arraycopy(typeListeners, 0, expandedTypeListeners, 0, typeListeners.length)
    expandedTypeListeners[-1] = listener
    listeners."${typeProperty}" = expandedTypeListeners
}
```